# Tag requirement issue when editing question on Facebook.Stackoverflow mini site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

When trying to edit [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7183849/fblogin-button-doesnt-work-without-show-faces), I am getting this error message:
[image: Error messaage]

> must include at least one tag not in 'facebook facebook-graph-api
>   facebook-connect facebook-c#-sdk facebook-fql facebook-like
>   facebook-javascript-sdk facebook-php-sdk facebook-iframe facebooker
>   facebook-iphone-sdk facebook-graph facebook-social-plugins
>   facebook-fbml facebook-page facebook-fanpage facebook-sharer
>   pyfacebook facebook-chat facebook-authentication facebook-android-sdk
>   facebooker2 facebook-oauth facebook-credits facebook-java-api
>   facebook-rest-api facebook-hacker-cup facebook-actionscript-api
>   facebook-wall facebooktoolkit facebook-widgets facebook-java-sdk
>   facebook-as3-api facebook-ads-api django-facebook phfacebook
>   facebook-ui facebook-read-only-api facebook-js-sdk facebook-ios
>   facebook-insights fbml'

Why am I required to have a separate tag when editing somebody elses question?  And did somebody really think this was a good error message?

Comment: Error message needs more facebook.

Comment: no we did not think this was a good error message, the trouble we are having is how to convey to the user that they need to use a tag in a list of 40 so we can accept the question. Thinking a custom error message will do for now ... eg: please enter a facebook related tag. with a link to the list of tags.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Facebook subsite of Stack Overflow was shut down years ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What, you don't like Facebook?

First, for the error message.  It will be changed to this:

[image]

with the next deploy.  The link will go to the FAQ [section containing the tags considered related "facebook"](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#tagsshown).  This is less [Malkovichian](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX9MtuqVrUQ&t=3m8s) I feel.

As [bemace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151987/bemace) surmises, using only Facebook tags on a question that's going to appear on a site dedicated to Facebook is... less than useful*.  We've also found out the hard way that single tag questions are kind of poor (and it gets even worse when you *suggest* a tag [like say, "facebook" via the site name], since then everyone just uses that one rather than think of an appropriate one).

So what we ended up doing is requiring a minimum of two tags, at least one of which must **not** be Facebook related.  I'm keeping an eye on how many people are running into this error, and may re-evaluate our position later.  It's much easier to relax restrictions than to tighten them, after all.

<sub>*There is a workaround, which is to ask the question directly on Stack Overflow instead, but that requires enough "inside baseball" knowledge of the system for us to give the user the benefit of the doubt.</sub>

Comment: What do you think of also adding a line to the error message like "If your programming question isn't about facebook you can ask it on [the main Stack Overflow site](http://stackoverflow.com)"?

Comment: Ok but why is it on me as the editor to add an additional tag? The original question asker should have been required. If they use the Stackoverflow back door - why should I as the editor be forced to switch to the SO back door?

Comment: @Off - The original asker should have spelled everything correctly and given it a clear, useful title too, but that's just not always how things turn out. That's why there are editors.

Comment: This is still kind of confusing. What if the question is about the [tag:facebook-graph-api] and nothing else? Like, a theoretical question about API limitations, and not about a specific language implementation? Do I need to tag-spam as [tag:api] to post it? Even if it's about the JavaScript implementation, I don't feel like I should tag it [tag:javascript] since it's SO Facebook specific.

Answer (score 3):

Just to chime in, I just asked a similar question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131489/question-validation-you-must-include-at-least-one-tag before realising that this thread existed.

I think this restriction needs to be loosened. [Facebook officially advertises this subsection as  a replacement for their forums](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/) so questions are most likely going to be directly and specifically related to certain aspects of FB and their development libraries and nothing else.

For example, If I have a query specifically about the return value of a particular Facebook Javascript SDK function, I would argue that I only need to tag it with `facebook` and `facebook-javascript-sdk` (or similar). I could go on to tag it with `javascript` or `api` or something, but these are actually harmful as someone with great javascript knowledge is unlikely to be able to help as this is facebook specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like "must include at least one non-facebook tag" would be a simpler message. I kind of suspect the limitation itself is by design though. Having only Facebook tags on a question doesn't help much to categorize things within the Facebook portal, so they *want* to force editors to add other tags so there are more useful groupings.

Answer (score 1):

This restriction, as described in the accepted answer, is meant to solve two problems. One of these problems is already solved, and the other one is a misconception. There would be no problem if this restriction were removed (especially as it's *already not present* on the main site), and there *are* problems the way it currently is.

The problem of generic, non-descriptive tags, like [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook), is a problem that applies to Stack Overflow as a whole (not just the Facebook mini site), and Stack Overflow already has a mechanism to solve it- **meta-tags**. Questions are already required to use one descriptive, non-meta tag to be posted. If [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) is a meta-tag (which I believe is already the case), that problem is solved, for the Facebook mini-site and the site as a whole.

The other surmised problem, as posited above, is "having only Facebook tags on a question doesn't help much to categorize things within the Facebook portal". **Having only Facebook tags on a question *does* help to categorize the question, *whether you're within the Facebook portal or not*.** Just because you're restricting the scope of your view to only show tags relating to Facebook, does not mean that there's no information in a tag that describes *in what way* that question relates to Facebook. Indeed, **which specific Facebook-related tags it has are often *the only way* you can classify the question**.

It would make *equally* as much sense to *disallow* tags unrelated to Facebook in this context as it does to *require* them. I could make the argument that I don't want to read questions about bugs in Google Chrome, that tangentially include its behavior on Facebook - *all I'm looking for is Facebook programming questions*. Such a restriction *absurdly restricts the tag vocabulary*, just as the current inclusion requirement absurdly *extends* it.

This restriction is harmful, because the only way to get around it is by *adding irrelevant tags*, which *reduces the usefulness of the other tags* - see Timmy O'Mahony's answer. It also *makes it harder to post your question*.

How you're filtering the tags when you're *browsing* shouldn't change your capabilities when you're *asking*.