# Let users post only Facebook-related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, mini-site, required-tags, facebook.stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag requirement issue when editing question on Facebook.Stackoverflow mini site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/tag-requirement-issue-when-editing-question-on-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site)

As said in my answer's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104023/the-like-tag-is-used-for-various-meanings/104026#comment-265903), I'm creating a new question about [like](/questions/tagged/like), [facebook-like](/questions/tagged/facebook-like) problem.

**What is problematic:**

When you want to submit question with tags only related to Facebook, it does not allow you to do so:

[image]

**What's result of this limitation:**

A lot of people do use [like](/questions/tagged/like) and other not-Facebook-related tags just to get around this limitation, without adding any meaningful information. It accomplishes nothing except clutter.

**What I propose**:

I'd propose to delete this limitation. I think it would get rid of most problems with Facebook tags.

Comment: Erm.. Why does this limitation even exist?

Comment: @Robert: Just a guess: To help creating some overlap between the facebook.so community and the rest of the community, which does not follow facebook-related tags, maybe?

Comment: @Paŭlo: That does make sense. Without at least a language tag, few will ever look at it, except maybe Facebook employees.

Comment: @Robert I lookup for all facebook questions

Comment: So maybe the message could be a bit more specific, and recommend some type of tag? *"For example, include your programming language."*

Comment: but with like-button, there is no need to add it. okay, HTML but I don't think it's necessary

Comment: See [Tag requirement issue when editing question on Facebook.Stackoverflow mini site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/tag-requirement-issue-when-editing-question-on-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site/103812#103812)

Comment: I can't see why this is necessary. If there's no programming language tag (which will necessarily be non-Facebook-related), then the question is probably not on topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

It won't take them long to figure out they can remove the `facebook.` part of the URL to go to regular Stack Overflow where that requirement is then lifted.  It is annoying, but I have used this several times already to edit existing Facebook questions that only have Facebook tags.  I agree though, the requirements should be consistent between both sites.

Comment: That's rather missing the point. Surely you can find a non-Facebook tag that applies to a Facebook programming question. Facebook isn't *that* special.

Comment: @OffBySome yesterday I tried to edit post. It failed, because it included only Facebook tags. So I left editing and it stays wrongly edited

Comment: If there's no programming language tag (which will necessarily be non-Facebook-related), then the question is probably not on topic for SO.