# Cleanup for the facebook-graph-api tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are four tags used for the Facebook Graph API on StackOverflow:

- [facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api) (2.7k questions, with Facebook logo)
- [facebook-graph](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph) (73, with Facebook logo)
- [graph-api](/questions/tagged/graph-api) (78, no logo - all questions have another Facebook-related tag or title)
- [fbgraph](/questions/tagged/fbgraph) (19, no logo)

Should/could some merging be done?

Comment: Add [tag:facebook-opengraph] and [tag:opengraph] to this list. Although there is *technically* a difference between the Open Graph Protocol and the Facebook Open Graph API, I'm not sure the question askers have been discriminating in the first place, so they can probably all be combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea -- I merged all these together.

(don't quite see the need for a synonym set, yet...)

Comment: There is still an issue with this - on facebook.stackoverflow.com I cannot save a question tagged with just [tag:facebook-graph-api]. It says I must use a non-Facebook tag. Even if the question is just about the graph api! (and is not programming language specific, etc) I usually have to tag-spam [tag:api] or something to get around this restriction. Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/tag-requirement-issue-when-editing-question-on-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site/