# opengraph, facebook-opengraph, and facebook-graph-api

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

Technically, "Open Graph", as I understand it, refers to a standard theoretically *anybody* could implement, not just Facebook (sort of like Microsoft's .NET).

However, in practice, [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph), [facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph), and [facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api), from what I can see, are used as synonyms (sort of like Microsoft's .NET).

Should any/all of these tags be merged? (At the very least it seems like [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) should get merged into [facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph), since it's already classified as a "Facebook tag".)

See also:
[Cleanup for the facebook-graph-api tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106386/cleanup-for-the-facebook-graph-api-tags)

Comment: (also, side note: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#tagsshown lists [tag:facebook-opengraph] twice.)

Comment: I just got stumped by this today. I was going to retag some questions that had both the `open` and `graph` tags, but I have no idea which tag to replace them with.

Comment: The `Graph API` is the generic name Facebook gave to their API.. I don't think it is synonymous with `opengraph`...

Comment: @Lix - true, but `opengraph` and `facebook-opengraph` is still valid.  Also, the question was `Should any/all of these tags be merged?`  I don't think that warrants a downvote.

Comment: @lit - You know what... You're right... I must have missed the `any/all`...

Comment: Huh, I guess since it's `Facebook` no one seems interested

Answer (score 1):

[facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api) is something very different than [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph).

[facebook-opengraph](/questions/tagged/facebook-opengraph) and [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) are just like [facebook-oauth](/questions/tagged/facebook-oauth) and [oauth](/questions/tagged/oauth) and shouldn't be merged.

Comment: [tag:opengraph] is already categorized as a Facebook tag. Out of 1,227 questions using it, 99.9% of these questions are about Facebook (and almost all of them are tagged [tag:facebook] to boot).