# Editing questions forces non-facebook tag on facebook.stackoverflow filter

Tags: support, tags, edits

When I am performing edits on questions in the http://facebook.stackoverflow.com filter, I am required to include a tag that is "not related to Facebook". (If there are none present)

[image]

I find myself having difficulty deciding what tags to choose.
Consider this (rather simple) example:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9147696/how-can-i-access-the-users-mobile-number-from-facebook-into-my-website

The only (original) tag was [facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api) and I added [mobile](/questions/tagged/mobile).
I understand that in most cases the tags *can* indeed be improved but why, when I'm viewing the *Facebook* filter does it require me to add a tag that is "not related to Facebook"?

---

**Update:**
I realized that the [mobile](/questions/tagged/mobile) tag was really not applicable (to the above question).  What I found as a "solution" was to leave the *Facebook* filter, returning to the "normal" [SO Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147696/how-can-i-access-the-users-mobile-number-from-facebook-into-my-website) where editing the post did not require that I add a non Facebook tag and removed the [mobile](/questions/tagged/mobile) tag.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103807/143965 except they only addressed the error message, not the fact that it requires a non-Facebook tab. Yes I agree, this requirement is annoying when editing FB questions.

Comment: Wow.. I guess I should have searched harder before asking :P  Great minds think alike! haha...  We have to stop running into each other like this ;)