# Assistance with tagging a question related to an API

Tags: support, tags

So I am in the [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) subview of Stack Overflow editing the body of a [question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10725669/how-i-can-get-session-key-from-graph-api). The question is language independent; it relates solely to the API.

*Is there a way to tag this correctly to Stack Overflow tagging semantics?*

[image: must include one tag not related to facebook]

Comment: What if you use the "problem" tag?

Comment: Hi, you must be new here. The common practice is to use an arbitrary, unrelated tag to get past the script and let the editors worry about it.

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121326/editing-questions-forces-non-facebook-tag-on-facebook-stackoverflow-filter) and also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/tag-requirement-issue-when-editing-question-on-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment above was tongue-in-cheek... In this case, you could've added the [api](/questions/tagged/api) tag, which would've fit the question perfectly. There are [13k+ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) with this tag on Stack Overflow and [1.6k+ questions](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) on Facebook.SO. I've now edited the [question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/10725669/616736) you linked to.

In general, finding non-FB tags shouldn't be that hard. The clues might be in the question or the existing tags. For example:

- [facebook-c#-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-c%23-sdk) → [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)
- [facebook-oauth](/questions/tagged/facebook-oauth) → [oauth](/questions/tagged/oauth) or [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication)

I do think that editors who merely fix the grammar and typos (and might not be domain experts) should not be forced to make a decision on *adding* a non-FB tag just to improve the site (removing inappropriate tags is OK). You could probably ask this as a separate [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this for other Facebook API questions from now on.